# removing all characters expect a-z 0-9 in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to remove all characters besides characters a-z and 0-9 in a bash file here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=-1
cat rtrans.txt | while read line
do
  i=$((i+1))
  for word in $line
  do
    echo "$i $word"|tr A-Z a-z|sed 's/[\._-]//g'
  done 
done > input1.test
```

However with sed it seems like I have to input all different non characters I want to remove.

This there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a character class

```
echo "$i $word" | tr A-Z a-z | sed -e 's/[^a-z0-9]//g'
```

this removes all characters *not* `^` in `[a-z0-9]`.

If you want to split a file into words and number the lines consecutively, you can also try

```
tr -s ' \t' '\n' <rtrans.txt | tr A-Z a-z | sed -e 's/[^a-z]//g' | nl -n ln -w1 -s ' '
```

Comment: I forgot to mention spaces as well, but adding a space between the number range and letter range seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `${var/Pattern/Replacement}` as suggested with bash [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

In your case, to remove from $word all characters besides a-z, A-Z and 0-9:

```
echo "$i ${word//[^a-zA-Z0-9]/}"
```